# CTEs in Oracle 10g - "unsupported column aliasing"

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I receive the following error when I try to execute a sql statement that uses a CTE:

```
ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing
32033. 00000 -  "unsupported column aliasing"
*Cause:    column aliasing in WITH clause is not supported yet
*Action:   specify aliasing in defintion subquery and retry
Error at Line: 1 Column: 9
```

The code I am trying to execute is:

```
WITH cte1
(
  SELECT *
  FROM test_table
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1;
```

I know this is a simple statement and there is no need to use a CTE, but I am just trying to start using CTEs in Oracle (I am coming from T-SQL).

Why doesn't the code execute?

Answer (score 9):

You're missing the AS:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM test_table
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1;
```

Answer (score 8):

I just figured this out - I need the AS keyword after the CTE name.  So the statement should be:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM test_table
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1;
```

Comment: you beat me by 15 seconds, glad you managed to resolve it by yourself!